# ¿Cuál es la palabra que se refiere a cuando uno cree que está haciendo el bien mientras en realidad está haciendo el mal?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, palabras-raras

Estoy escribiendo un ensayo en el que critico cómo unos editores modificaron la ortografía de un fragmento, creyendo que estaban actualizando la ortografía del texto, y al hacerlo arruinaron el significado del fragmento completamente. No sé con qué palabra nombrar esta clase de actos bienintencionados que terminan mal.

Answer (score 4):

Estaríamos hablando de un [desatino](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CVw8sf6), de un [despropósito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DQ4TgJy), de una [necedad](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QKKCXBU), de una [pifia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SxvzhuK), de [pasarse de listo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S33P1kX#BPZfTIH), de [desgraciar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D1vo9eX%7CD1w6We5) el texto... Sin entrar en las más habituales, aunque no más acertadas: [tontería](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a1WOOYo), [estupidez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H2ZTc2O), [cagada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6c5i5sA), etc.

Si queremos suavizarlo un poco, podemos llamarlo una [malhadada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O2Jhl8o) equivocación, un [desacierto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CL6G2tA), una [cándida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=76UgiU7) [metedura de pata](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM#8arje3S)...

También podemos tirar de expresiones populares y decir que [han hecho un pan como unas hostias](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RcmAvfa#7Q7Rn2M), o que estamos ante el nuevo [Cristo de Borja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecce_Homo_de_Borja) de la literatura.

Answer (score 1):

Interesante cuestión. Para empezar la ronda de respuestas y a falta de una opción mejor, yo propongo *desafortunado*:

> **[desafortunado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CNPnZdH)**
>
> 1. adj. Carente de fortuna.
> 2. adj. Desacertado, inoportuno.

Como puedes ver, también valdría *desacertado*:

> **[desacertado, da](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CL11mz0)**
>
> Del part. de *desacertar*.
>
> 1. adj. Que yerra u obra sin acierto.

La acepción "carente de fortuna" para *desafortunado* entiendo que usa *[fortuna](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IHQ5l0O)* en el sentido de "suerte favorable" o *[éxito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HGAP1jB)* ("buena aceptación"), lo que convierte un acto desafortunado en algo que pretendía tener fortuna (éxito, buena aceptación, se entiende que con buena intención), pero no la ha tenido.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo

**estropear las cosas**

[Estropear](https://dle.rae.es/?id=H0dheap): Echar a perder, malograr cualquier asunto o proyecto

No encuentro una fuente, pero "estropear las cosas" da a entender la idea de que pintaste un cuadro, pero no supiste cuándo dejarlo ya, y seguiste agregando detalles y más detalles y por fin todo se echó a perder.